# How to display subcategories in wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

Hello I have a script that displays all categories in wordpress menu but I want to add subcategories to this menu too. How I can check if categories have subcategories then display them in submenu of category.

```
$items .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';  
$categories = get_categories();  
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $option = '<li><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'">';
    $option .= $category->cat_name;
    $option .= '</a></li>';         
    $items .= $option;
}    
$items .= '</ul></li>';
```

Comment: you could always use [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Comment: But how I can check if category has child and then display it in ul

Comment: look at the codex . It should also list childrens .. If you want to manuallycheck , you can do so with [get_term_children()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children)

Comment: Can you check this http://pastebin.com/Fq8dAF2B because it doesn't work.

Comment: Check out this link, it may give some hints. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/showing-subcategories-of-a-parent-page-under-subcategory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_categories() only fetches categories and subcategories those are assigned to any post(s) unless you pass array("hide_empty"=>0) as parameter to fetch inactive categories/subcategories  too

try below

```
$items .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';  
$categories = get_categories(array("hide_empty"=>0,'parent'=> '0'));  
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $childrens = get_categories(array('child_of'=>$category->term_id,"hide_empty"=>0));
    $subitems ='';
    if(count($childrens)>0){
        $subitems .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';  
        foreach($childrens as $children){
            $opt = '<li><a href="'.get_category_link($children->term_id ).'">';
            $opt .= $children->cat_name;
            $opt .= '</a></li>';         
            $subitems .= $opt;  
        }
        $subitems.= '</ul></li>';
    }
    $option = '<li><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'">';
    $option .= $category->cat_name;
    $option .= '</a>'.$subitems.'</li>';         
    $items .= $option;
}    
$items .= '</ul></li>';
```

I know its a dirty way. Don't use "hide_empty"=>0 unless you really need it

Comment: It was helpful thanks, but i don't know how to separate subcategories in other ul from categories. Can you help me with this?